# Show splash screen during u-boot using bmp command on Raspberry CM3+

Tags: video, raspberry-pi3, splash-screen, u-boot

I'm trying to show a bootscreen during the boot of my Yocto-build distribution. This runs on a Compute Module 3+ (CM3+). Here's what I figured out so far:

- Compile u-boot with `CONFIG_CMD_BMP=y` and `CONFIG_DM_VIDEO=y`
- Place a bitmap image on the boot partition and load it with `fatload mmc 0:1 $loadaddr /splash.bmp`
- Check that the bitmap was loaded correctly:

```
U-Boot> bmp info $loadaddr
Image size    : 480 x 800
Bits per pixel: 24
Compression   : 0
```

The last step would be to display it, but `bmp display $loadaddr 0 0` simply does nothing and also spits out no error. I found out that this is due to [this line here](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/cmd/bmp.c#L255) returns a 0. This seems to indicate that there is no video support for my board.

Now to the actual questions:

- What could I do to enable video support for u-boot on the the Pi?
- Is there generic HDMI video output? If yes, how do I enable it?
- Do I need to supply my own video driver implementation?
- I see the log output over the vidconsole. How is that working?

Also my u-boot version is:

```
U-Boot> version
U-Boot 2019.01-dirty (Jan 01 1970 - 00:00:00 +0000)

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 8.3.0
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.32.0.20190204
```

EDIT: Looking a bit more, there is actually a [bcm2835](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/drivers/video/bcm2835.c) video driver. It can be activated via `CONFIG_VIDEO_BCM2835=y`, but it doesn't seem to load. This is most likely because [I don't get the right device tree nodes passed](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/drivers/video/bcm2835.c#L52). Any clues why that could be?

EDIT 2: False alarm, the video driver loads fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a bitmap with 24 bit, so I also needed to define `CONFIG_BMP_24BPP` so the relevant support code is compiled-in ([see here](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/drivers/video/video_bmp.c#L317)). Better error handling code would have been great here. :)